# Canvas.toDataURL fails when rendering SVG with clip-path

Tags: javascript, svg, canvas, browser

I am attempting to convert a generated SVG into a PNG/JPG via HTML5 Canvas. So far this method works with everything I have thrown at it, barring one exception. When an element in the source SVG has a `clip-path` attribute, `canvas.toDataURL()` returns an empty url (i.e. `data;`).

These are the relevant functions I am using to perform the conversion.

```js
// expects svg dataurl
// returns a dataurl
async function _svgToRasterImage(url, options) {
  const image = await _svgToImageElement(url)

  const context = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d', {
    antialias: options.rasterAA
  })
  context.canvas.width  = options.rasterW || image.width
  context.canvas.height = options.rasterH || image.height
  context.drawImage(image,
    0, 0,          image.width,          image.height,
    0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height
  )

  return context.canvas.toDataURL(
    options.rasterTarget,
    options.rasterQuality
  )
}

// expects svg dataurl
// returns an SVGImageElement
function _svgToImageElement(url) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    const image = new Image()
    image.addEventListener(
      'load',
      resolve(image),
      { once: true }
    )
    image.src = url
  })
}
```

Here is an example of a problematic SVG
(I have abbreviated some of the embedded elements e.g. `href="data:image/png;base64,..."`).

```xml
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.dev/svgjs" width="180" height="252">
  <svg width="180" height="252" x="0" y="0">
    <g>
      <rect width="162" height="226.8" x="9" y="12.600000000000001" fill-opacity="0" rx="7.2" ry="7.2" stroke-width="7.2" stroke="#00ff00"/>
    </g>
    <g>
      <ellipse rx="81" ry="113.4" cx="90" cy="126" fill-opacity="0" stroke-width="7.2" stroke="#0000ff"/>
    </g>
    <g clip-path="url(&quot;#SvgjsClipPath1009&quot;)">
      <image width="256" height="256" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,..." transform="matrix(0.6328125,0,0,0.6328125,9,45.00000000000001)"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="SvgjsClipPath1009">
      <rect width="162" height="226.8" x="9" y="12.600000000000001"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

While I am not certain, I am confident that the above SVG is valid because it renders correctly in the DOM in both Chrome and Firefox; however, there is a distinct possibility that I am missing something obvious that the browser is ignoring (or fixing for me in this case)!

Comment: So you have that SVG markup in a file at the `url` you pass to the function? Is the `&quot:` a bad copy-paste thing?

Comment: Yes, I am passing an SVG dataurl encoded in base64 to the function (e.g. `data:image/svg+xml;base64,...`. 

I am using [SVG.js](https://svgjs.dev/docs/3.0/) to generate the SVG images. The `&quot;` is automatically escaped by this library. Initially I thought this was strange as well; however, other embedded assets (such as fonts) use an identical `url(&quot;...&quot;)` scheme and they do not cause problems.

Comment: Your image loader has a bug, it's not waiting for the image has loaded before calling `resolve(img)`, it sets the result of this call as the handler to the event and thus calls it directly. https://jsfiddle.net/tmqah64o/

Comment: I rolled back your last edit, StackSnippets are only meant for actual runnable code snippets. This snippet doesn't do anything and thus doesn't need a StackSnippet.

Comment: That is remarkable, arrow functions have bested me again. I'm curious why this bug only occurs when `clip-path` is present, since it doesn't seem related? I am testing your solution in my actual codebase as we speak and it works perfectly. What baffles me is that I could render images without clip-path just fine??

Comment: Probably your browser was able to render the whole svg almost synchronously, but to get the clip-path they go on an async path (clip-path normally *can* incur a Network Request since they *can* point to  an external file, though in an <img> it can't do that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@Kaiido](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74398446/canvas-todataurl-fails-when-rendering-svg-with-clip-path?noredirect=1#comment131340903_74398446) for the help!

> Your image loader has a bug, it's not waiting for the image has loaded before calling resolve(img), it sets the result of this call as the handler to the event and thus calls it directly.

The solution is to use an arrow function in the callback of the event listener because calling `resolve(image)` directly will immediately execute, resolving the promise before the image actually loads.

```js
function _svgToImageElement(url) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    const image = new Image()
    image.addEventListener(
      'load',
      e => resolve(image), // <-- DO
      //   resolve(image),    <-- DON'T
      { once: true }
    )
    image.src = url
  })
}
```

It is amazing how much pain 3 missing characters can cause.